# Invocar g++ 4.9 con g++

Tags: gcc

Deseo instalar la version 4.9 o superior de g++. El problema que he encontrado es que para invocarlo necesito teclear g++-4.9. Hay alguna forma de instalar y/o configurar esta versión de g++ para para invocarla de la forma en la que deseo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo. Simplemente tenia que cambiar el link simbólico de g++ ubicado en /usr/bin que apuntaba a /usr/bin/g++-4.8.5.

El primer paso es borrar el link con 'sudo rm /usr/bin/g++'(sin comillas).

El segundo paso es crear otro link simbólico con el mismo nombre pero que apunte a la carpeta /usr/bin/g++-4.9 de esta manera: 
'sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++'